# PHP - mail with attachments - message not showing

Tags: php, email, attachment

I am trying to complete sending mail with attachments

**Problem**: Email is sending without message body and attachments

**Goal**: send `utf-8` `html` email with attachments

I created so far ...

Usage:

**email_library.php**

```
<?php

    private function create_body()
    {
        $this->body[] = "--{$this->uid}";
        $this->body[] = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8";
        $this->body[] = "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit";
        $this->body[] = $this->message;

        if (!empty($this->attachments)) {

            foreach ($this->attachments as $k => $a) {
                $this->body[] = "--{$this->uid}";
                $this->body[] = "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"{$a['name']}\"";
                $this->body[] = "Content-Description: {$a['name']}";
                $this->body[] = "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64";
                $this->body[] = "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$a['name']}\"";
                $this->body[] = "{$a['data']}";
            }

        }
        $this->body[] = "--{$this->uid}--";

    }
```

EDIT:

```
$this->body[] = "--{$this->uid}";
```

removing `"--"`

The encapsulation boundary following the last body part is a distinguished delimiter that indicates that no further body parts will follow.

Comment: on first sight your script looks okay to me... Have you tried sending an email without attachment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with a multipart message, you need to separate each part (message body + attachments) with *two* line breaks before the `--==MIME_BOUNDARY`! Otherwise they do not separate properly in your message.

Simply add `\n` to your existing code:

```
$this->body[] = $this->message."\n\n";
...
$this->body[] = "{$a['data']}\n\n";
```

**Disclaimer:** I have not tested any of this, hopefully it works.

For more information, check out [RFC 1521](http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1521/16.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Watch out for https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68776 - multiple linebreaks are not allowed anymore, for me DOOManiac answer is not working (anymore).